# toggling a div when a text area is typed in or not

Tags: javascript, html

Any idea why this function isn't working? I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hoodleehoo/8wxwe9rd/

Here's the function I have:

```
$("#answer").on('input',function(e){
          if(e.target.value === ''){
            // Textarea has no value
            document.getElementById('hotpages1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('hotpages2').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            // Textarea has a value
            document.getElementById('hotpages1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('hotpages2').style.display = 'block';
          }
    });
```

The goal is to have a div change it's display style based on whether the textarea is typed in. If the text is deleted and the text area is again blank it should toggle back to what it was originally.

UPDATE:

Okay, I forgot to put the jquery in the jsfiddle which I picked up on right after I posted this, but that didn't fix the issue on my page. After a ton of trial and error it turns out the function needs to be placed after the form, not before or inside. After moving the function to the bottom of the page it works beautifully!

Comment: Add jQuery library to fiddle! [see](http://jsfiddle.net/8wxwe9rd/4/)

Comment: "no library (pure js)" doesn't have `$()`...

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to reference *jQuery* in the fiddle.

I changed the event to `keyup`, [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) also works. `input`'s a newer event, consult the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility).

```
$("#answer").on('keyup', function (e) {
    var hot1 = document.getElementById('hotpages1'),
    hot2 = document.getElementById('hotpages2');
    if (e.target.value === '') {
        hot1.style.display = 'block';
        hot2.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        hot1.style.display = 'none';
        hot2.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8wxwe9rd/5/